# Google security certificate error

Tags: security

I am recently having this error when trying to access google (and google only).

[image]

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: This question should be moved to superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's telling you to fix your clock because it looks wrong.

Also try to clear your cache and cookies and try again.

Comment: hahaha I missed it. My fault. Thanks

Comment: remember to read the error before asking a question :) Have fun